# tapered div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a tapered `<div>` tag. That is, a slant edge on one side (slanting inwards) and a straight edge on all the other 3 sides.

I'm not sure if it is possible using CSS and HTML alone. I've tried Googling this problem, but could not find any solution to it.

I've tried:

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius : 50px 650px;
```

where 650px is the whole height if my div. But this gives me a rounded corner for the bottom right position, which I don't want. Hope you guys know the answer to this problem, or at least suggest an alternative to this.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you want the `slant`?

Comment: Can you post an image of your desired output?

Comment: you can have a look at this trapezium  [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid] , as mentioned in one of the comments. This image with three sides at right angles, and one tapered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This [can be achieved](http://plnkr.co/edit/DmbiizPfycqTOG9Wqp0B?p=preview) with [transparent border](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)!

*CSS*

```
#test1 {
  border-top: 100px solid red;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;

  width: 300px;
}

#test2 {
  border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

#test3 {
  border-top: 100px solid red;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    content: 'ds';
  z-index: -1; /* make it the background */
}

#test3 .content {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left; /* wrap the text */
    clear: left; /* for demo */
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

*HTML*

```
  <body>
    <div id="test1">
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div id="test2">
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div id="test3">
      <div class="content">
        Watch for the<br>
        new lines. <br>
        Do not overlap.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This isn't tapered.  This creates a 5th side, whereas OP wants 3 regular sides and one that is just not straight / consistent with the others.  Let me describe it this way: Imagine a square.  Now, imagine the bottom side is shortened from the right.  This would make the right side slant inwards.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, as it achieved the shape I want in test#2. However, I can't add elements inside `<div>` tag as the shape is of the border.

Comment: @madhead Very nice trick!  Rijul, I think your best bet would be to overlay your content in another div positioned on top of the shape one, if you want to use this method.

Comment: @Rijul See updated plunk. You can relative-position content. However this solution is not so good - you need to be sure your content will not overlap div. It may be suitable for headers and titles, but not for user-generated content.

Comment: Very goos trick. Thanks. I was planning on using the `div` overlap anyways, because of the previous suggestion by Wayne. Thanks for demonstrating it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like CSS regions might http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html (scroll down to the section entitled "Wrap shape"). You could define the shape as a polygon and you're set! Unfortunately, shaped region support is currently limited, but depending on your use case, it might work.